# How to provide a string from an external source, such as from an HTTP request for C++

Tags: c++

I have been tasked to write a C++ program that is specified as such:

"write a method to reverse an arbitrary string provided as a null terminated char* from an external source, such as from an HTTP request."

So: I made this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void reverse(char *s)
{
    cout << s <<endl;
    int len = strlen(s);
    char *head = s;
    char *tail = &s[len-1];
    while (head < tail)
        swap(*head++, *tail--);
    cout << s <<endl;

}

int main()
{
    char test[] = "monkey";
    reverse(test);

}
```

This correctly reverses monkey, but I don't know if I have completed this problem correctly. The part where it says the string comes from an  "external source, such as from an HTTP request"? What does that mean? How can I make my program do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably talking about taking command line arguments: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

You could do something like this with your code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i){
        reverse(argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This would allow you to accept strings from the command line and reverse them. Note that each space will create a separate string.

You can see [a live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/198d5dae047234e1) of my `main`, with your `reverse` implementation, and the input: hello world

Additionally, C++ already provides a [`reverse`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/) implementation. You can see a live example here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d554697336958cb

You can test piping whatever strings you want to your executable. Corilu is nice in that you can type in command line arguments to pass in, you can see I've passed in:

> hello world

But if you build the executable on your machine you can pipe whatever arguments you'd like to it.

Comment: The library version of `reverse` accepts an iterator range, and the question gives the input as a null-terminated string. That makes it actually a good interview question: do you use the library version? If so, how do you create the iterator range? If not, why is our alternative better?

Comment: @MSalters It's personal preference for the most part (mine being to use something in the standard.) But I mostly wanted to include that link cause http://www.cplusplus.com puts possible implementation code in most of their algorithm pages and I thought that might be a helpful reference.